# how to login with linked in with windows Application in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Want to authenticate users via **linkedin**  in my desktop application c#.any one know know how to integrate ?

Comment: Did you check Linkedin's [developer site](https://developer.linkedin.com/)? Did you try the tutorials? Are you having a specific problem? The `Getting Started` page starts with `Authentication`

Comment: it is ok with web app but ..wanna know that is there any way for the windows app .

Comment: Web app or desktop, the REST API is the same. Check the site and the tools. You'll probably find samples and libraries in there

Comment: no body have answer of my question .:)

Comment: On the contrary, many people responded either directly or with their downvotes that this is a poorly-worded question. It's not suitable for Stack Overflow. The question can easily be answered by the API's documentation, which also contains samples. If you have a problem with the samples, *explain the specific problem, showing the code you used*. Don't expect others to write the code for you. You'd better post a new question though, as this one has received so many downvotes no-one will respond to it

Answer (score 1):

You require the LinkedIn API using OAuth2 to integrate within your C# program.

https://developer.linkedin.com/apis has more info.

Comment: That is only example for web application not for windows

Comment: The web service call is used for both forms and asp.net

Comment: have u any example regarding this issue ?

Comment: Sajidlodi - Here is a Github project that simplifies OAuth2 with LinkedIn included: https://github.com/titarenko/OAuth2